# What is the difference concerning two questions in probability?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, probability-limit-theorems

I have been looking through the material, the lecturer gave me, concerning the subject of Stochastic Processes. Whilst solving through some of them, I stumbled upon a question (well, actually two subquestions), which I don't see the difference in, however, I think the difference is certainly there, and I am just negligent.

The task says:

Suppose we have the following infinitely descending chain of choices (something like an inverse of a shell game), where at each step you have to choose $1$ of $3$ shells, under which there may be either a red or a black pearl. There is only one red pearl among all three shells. If at some trial you withdraw a red pearl, the game stops.

(Now, to the part, I don't really get.)

1. What is the probability that you will never withdraw a red pearl, if you choose the shell randomly at every step.

I may be misteken, but here we just have to count the probability to withdraw black pearls from the shells, which is: $\frac{2}{3}$ for each game trial, and hence, once we infinitely try this, the probability of not withdrawing the read pearl should be $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n = 0.$$
(I may be mistaken, but anyways)

2. What is the probability that there is at least one such **eternal game**, so that you do not withdraw the red pearl at all?

For me it seems like the question is pretty same to that of (1), but I don't think that the author would have simply separated these two questions.

Can anyone, please, explain me, what is the difference between them, and if they are different, then in what way, and how should I proceed with that?

Thank you a lot in advance!

UPD: I forgot to mention, that you have no way to know, under which shell the red pearl appears, and each next game's pearls arrangement is independent from the previous one.

Comment: It also seems like the same questions to me. Maybe the first one was just for a finite game ($n$ draws)?

Comment: I don't understand the question very well.  If you were to look at the sample space as the possible game outcomes, if we were to formalize the problem either the sample space does or does not include the possibility of the "eternal game" and both choices would have been valid.  As for (1), the probability that we required more than $n$ turns to find a red pearl is indeed $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ and the probability "*you will never withdraw a red pearl*" (*if such a thing made sense*) is [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) zero.

Comment: I agree that they seem to be pretty much the same question.  I would ask the lecturer about it.  The only thing I could think is it that it might be getting at the difference between "almost never" and "never:" while the probability of getting an eternal game is $0$, there are still such eternal games in the sample space.

Comment: As for the second question... "*what is the probability there is at least one such eternal game*"... the probability there is at least one among what... within the sample space?  That is etiher zero or one depending on your choice of the sample space.  Among $n$ randomly selected games from the sample space?  Zero.  Among $n$ results of the experiment?  Also zero.

Comment: If $p$ is the probability of observing an eternal game, then by conditioning on your first colored pearl it's easy to see that $p=\frac{2}{3}p$ which implies $p=0$.

Comment: @JMoravits, I think, we may interpret this question (2) as follows: Say we have some infinite space of possible game outcomes, before we stop it: like BBBBR or BR, or just R. Then, what is the probability to observe such a game, that it's neverending outcome is BBBBBB..., so that the game doesn't halt.

Comment: "*What is the probability to observe such a game*"  Zero, almost surely.  The question of whether an eternal game exists in the sample space however is in my opinion ambiguous until you clarify things further with both options being possible.  The existence of an eternal game in the sample space is moot however for the most part since any such eternal games if they exist would comprise a null-set and occur with probability zero.  I see nothing wrong with stating that the sequences considered must be of finite (*albeit unbounded*) length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What is the probability that there is at least one such eternal game, so that you do not withdraw the red pearl at all?"

This sentence doesn't make that much sense. We don't talk about the probability of mathematical statements, we talk about probabilities of events in the event space.

The claim that "there exists at least one such eternal game, so that you do not withdraw the red pearl at all" is true (satisfied by the event: Black, Black, Black, Black, ...). However, the probability measure of that event is zero.

So, if the author was trying to get at whether the claim is true or not, you could say it's "100% true", so to speak.

Comment: By the 'claim' you mean, that there is no such game, so that we have "BBBB..." infinite sequence? It's just I was also thinking about it in that way, so to speak, but essentially, such a problem statement leads us back to the definition of the (1) subquestion, so I still see no purpose in separating them.

Comment: the claim is that there IS at least one such game. how do we prove that there is one such game? we simply offer the example of BBBB.... this game satisfies the event of never picking red

Comment: So, the second question may suffice me to simply provide an example of such a sequence, the probability of the existance of which is 1, as far as we have just drawn it? Because, if it is so, the second question now does make sense in a way, that we have to elaborate on existance of such a game at all.

Answer (score 1):

The question $(1)$ is asking what is the probability that "no red pearl" game happens.  You rightly stated probability is limit $(2/3)^n$, so $0$%.

Question $(2)$ is asking if the "no red pearl" game itself exists.  Well it does exist, with $100$% certainty

I think the question is pointing out that even if "no red pearl" game can happen (which intuitively means it should have >0% probaility of happening), our intuition breaks down when dealing with infinity (in this case, "no red pearl" game will not happen almost surely, but it can happen definitely)